# Adding multiple CATextLayers with animations to CALayer not working properly

Tags: swift, uikit, avfoundation

I am burning some custom captions into a video by animating each line of text with a `CATextLayer()` plus `CAKeyframeAnimation()` with changes in opacity.

I am struggling to detect why sometimes some lines do not appear. Most of the times is just the first line which does not appear (seems random).

Here is my function for burning a line of subtitles:

```
let textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.string = createNSStringFromWords(string: subtitles.lineText, textSize: size)
textLayer.shouldRasterize = true
textLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
textLayer.alignmentMode = .center
textLayer.frame = CGRect(
    x: 0,
    y: videoSize.height * 0.11,
    width: videoSize.width,
    height: 200)

textLayer.displayIfNeeded()
textLayer.opacity = 0

// MARK: - Text animation
let opacityAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
opacityAnimation.beginTime = subtitles.startTime
opacityAnimation.duration = (subtitles.endTime - subtitles.startTime)

// Opacity animation style
opacityAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
opacityAnimation.values = [0.2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
opacityAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1]
opacityAnimation.autoreverses = false

// What happens when we end the animation
opacityAnimation.fillMode = .removed
opacityAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

// Add the final result and iterate
textLayer.add(opacityAnimation, forKey: "opacity")
targetLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
```

I run this for every line of text to add, adding each to the same `CALayer`(textLayer). I checked the input subtitles and the seem to be correct in time and text. I also checked the animations and they seem to be fine.

The only difference between the first one and the rest it seems to be the initial start (0) and the duration (typically > 1.0 seconds). Not sure about where to go next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you speak of "the initial start (0)" is suspect. You are not showing sufficient code, but it is crucial that your animation begin times be expressed in terms of AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero and I see no evidence that you are doing that. You cannot use 0, as it will be replaced with `CACurrentMediaTime()`.

Comment: Indeed, I was passing a Double for the time.

Comment: Thank you so much @matt, that was exactly what was causing the problem. Could you provide any reference for learning more about animations? many thanks